# Need to Backup and Restore a database

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, overwrite

I need to create a script that when I execute it. It will backup a production database (keep in mind this is a live database) and restore it as development database(if exists overwrite)

I have tried this query but getting error message. I need to find a way to do this without taking the database offline or single user mode

```
USE [master]
    RESTORE DATABASE [Development] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Production.bak' 
       WITH  FILE = 6,  MOVE N'Producation' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Development.mdf', 
       MOVE N'Production_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Development_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
```

> Msg 3101, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
>   Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I do not need to keep the development online and can kill connections.

so I have used the `ALTER DATABASE [ALI] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO` to resolve this error